# CSV file upload not working with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I'm using below code for upload csv files. It is always saying "invalid file error". How can I fix this issue?

Here is my form:

```
<form name="bulk_dealer" action="<?= base_url() ?>admin/add_bulk_user" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"  enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <ul>  
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-field"><label for="csvfile">Upload dealer id file( *only .csv) :</label></li> 
            <li class="ui-input"><input type="file" name="csvfile" value="" placeholder="" required=""></li>  
            <li><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload" class="ui-submit"></li>  
        </ul>
    </ul>  
</form>
```

here is my controller

```
function add_bulk_user() {
    $data['add_bulk_user_errors'] = NULL;
    $data['add_bulk_user_success'] = NULL;       

    if ($this->input->post() !== FALSE) {
        $config_arr = array(
            'upload_path' => './uploads/csv/',
            'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text/csv|csv',
            'max_size' => '2048',
            'max_width' => '1024',
            'max_height' => '768',
            'encrypt_name' => true,
            'file_name' => 'dealer'
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config_arr);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('csvfile')) {
            $data['add_bulk_user_errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); // this isn't working                
        } else {
            $csvfilepath = "uploads/csv/" . $config_arr['file_name'];
            $this->addfromcsv($csvfilepath);
            $data['qs'] = $this->upload->data();
            $row = 1;

            if (($handle = fopen("./uploads/csv/dealer.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $num = count($data);
                    $row++;
                    for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {

                        $this->load->model("login_model");
                        $is_esist = $this->login_model->check_is_exist($data[$c]);
                        if ($is_esist) {

                        } else {
                            $this->login_model->set_login($data[$c], 'dealer@ceat123');
                        }
                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }

            $data['add_bulk_user_success'] = "File Uploaded Successfully";
        }

        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/add';

        $this->load->view('admin_layout', $data);
        redirect('admin/add_bulk_user', 'refresh');
    } else {
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/add';
        $this->load->view('admin_layout', $data);
    }
}
```

mimes.php

```
$mimes = array( 'hqx'   =>  'application/mac-binhex40',
            'cpt'   =>  'application/mac-compactpro',
            'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel'),
            'bin'   =>  'application/macbinary',
            'dms'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'lha'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'lzh'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'exe'   =>  array('application/octet-stream', 'application/x-msdownload'),
            'class' =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'psd'   =>  'application/x-photoshop',
            'so'    =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'sea'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'dll'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
            'oda'   =>  'application/oda',
            'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download'),
            'ai'    =>  'application/postscript',
            'eps'   =>  'application/postscript',
            'ps'    =>  'application/postscript',
            'smi'   =>  'application/smil',
            'smil'  =>  'application/smil',
            'mif'   =>  'application/vnd.mif',
            'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel'),
            'ppt'   =>  array('application/powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'),
            'wbxml' =>  'application/wbxml',
            'wmlc'  =>  'application/wmlc',
            'dcr'   =>  'application/x-director',
            'dir'   =>  'application/x-director',
            'dxr'   =>  'application/x-director',
            'dvi'   =>  'application/x-dvi',
            'gtar'  =>  'application/x-gtar',
            'gz'    =>  'application/x-gzip',
            'php'   =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
            'php4'  =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
            'php3'  =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
            'phtml' =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
            'phps'  =>  'application/x-httpd-php-source',
            'js'    =>  'application/x-javascript',
            'swf'   =>  'application/x-shockwave-flash',
            'sit'   =>  'application/x-stuffit',
            'tar'   =>  'application/x-tar',
            'tgz'   =>  array('application/x-tar', 'application/x-gzip-compressed'),
            'xhtml' =>  'application/xhtml+xml',
            'xht'   =>  'application/xhtml+xml',
            'zip'   =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed'),
            'mid'   =>  'audio/midi',
            'midi'  =>  'audio/midi',
            'mpga'  =>  'audio/mpeg',
            'mp2'   =>  'audio/mpeg',
            'mp3'   =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3'),
            'aif'   =>  'audio/x-aiff',
            'aiff'  =>  'audio/x-aiff',
            'aifc'  =>  'audio/x-aiff',
            'ram'   =>  'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
            'rm'    =>  'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
            'rpm'   =>  'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin',
            'ra'    =>  'audio/x-realaudio',
            'rv'    =>  'video/vnd.rn-realvideo',
            'wav'   =>  array('audio/x-wav', 'audio/wave', 'audio/wav'),
            'bmp'   =>  array('image/bmp', 'image/x-windows-bmp'),
            'gif'   =>  'image/gif',
            'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
            'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
            'jpe'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
            'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png'),
            'tiff'  =>  'image/tiff',
            'tif'   =>  'image/tiff',
            'css'   =>  'text/css',
            'html'  =>  'text/html',
            'htm'   =>  'text/html',
            'shtml' =>  'text/html',
            'txt'   =>  'text/plain',
            'text'  =>  'text/plain',
            'log'   =>  array('text/plain', 'text/x-log'),
            'rtx'   =>  'text/richtext',
            'rtf'   =>  'text/rtf',
            'xml'   =>  'text/xml',
            'xsl'   =>  'text/xml',
            'mpeg'  =>  'video/mpeg',
            'mpg'   =>  'video/mpeg',
            'mpe'   =>  'video/mpeg',
            'qt'    =>  'video/quicktime',
            'mov'   =>  'video/quicktime',
            'avi'   =>  'video/x-msvideo',
            'movie' =>  'video/x-sgi-movie',
            'doc'   =>  'application/msword',
            'docx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
            'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
            'word'  =>  array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream'),
            'xl'    =>  'application/excel',
            'eml'   =>  'message/rfc822',
            'json' => array('application/json', 'text/json')
        );
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting exactly? File is invalid or file type invalid?

Comment: @kumar_v its saying  file type is invalid

Comment: print_r($_FILES); to check the `type` and add in MIME if not listed.

Comment: Hi, in just give 'allowed_types' => 'csv'. you can see in mimes.php all csv mime type given if you want to add any mime type to csv just add and element to array of csv of mimetypes array

Comment: add allowed_types=>'*'

Comment: @kumar_v Array ( [csvfile] => Array ( [name] => Mage_Adminhtml.csv [type] => text/csv [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbAiG9q [error] => 0 [size] => 65930 ) ) 
Array ( [add_bulk_user_errors] =>
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: Did you try Joran solution?

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload('csvfile') does this function is working or not?
every time your controll goes to in if condition never goes to else ?

Comment: @kumar_v i have changed like that. But not worked,when i use   allowed_types=>'*' , then file uploading.

Comment: replace `'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text/csv|csv',` with `'allowed_types' => 'csv',`

Comment: @kumar_v getting same error. The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: @sanji if my answer didn't work, please comment below it.. I'll get a notification and could look into it to come with a new answer. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
'allowed_types'=> 'csv',
```

On your root directory go to `application -> config -> mimes.php` in csv add `'text/plain'`

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `csv` element in the `config/mimes.php` to:

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel'), ...
```

All I added was `text/plain`. This did it for me.

Comment: This helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using linux, find mime-type using following command
        `file --mime-type filename`

add the mime-type in csv of `application > config > mimes.php`

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

my var_dump($_FILES) gives
Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => testa.csv [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpI9TwZT [error] => 0 [size] => 232 ) )

works fine on localhost but not online.

Same set of code working same controller in one function and not in another

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text/csv|csv',
```

With:

```
'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text/anytext|csv|text/x-comma-separated-values|text/comma-separated-values|application/octet-stream|application/vnd.ms-excel|application/x-csv|text/x-csv|text/csv|application/csv|application/excel|application/vnd.msexcel',
```

Oh, and WHY are you using a max width and height for a CSV file?

```
'max_width' => '1024',
'max_height' => '768',
```

remove them ;)

Comment: this also not worked for me.whe i use 'allowed_types' => '*' then its working.

Comment: Ok, do the following: Add `var_dump($_FILES);` just below `function add_bulk_user() {` and run the page again. Then copy the page source and paste it here. Then we can see what the file mime really is of your file and we could fix it within seconds.

Comment: 'array (size=1)
  'csvfile' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'dealerhsgdhgshf.csv' (length=19)
      'type' => string 'text/csv' (length=8)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpyFVpgi' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 135'
Array ( [add_bulk_user_errors] =>
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

change the bellow code it can be working fine

```
 'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text/csv|csv',
```

repalce with

```
   'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text|csv|csv',
```