# Codeigniter error: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I upload a `csv` file, there is no problem on `localhost` and everything works fine, but when I upload my app on live server and upload a `csv` file then this error thrown: `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.` I am confused as to why this happens. Please help me to solve this.

For my `localhost` environment, I am using XAMPP and CodeIgniter.

I only want to allow `csv` file uploads.

Comment: Would be use full if you could edit your post and place your controller for upload and view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399056/csv-file-upload-not-working-with-codeigniter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201741/upload-pdf-csv-and-other-file-type-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check 2 things:

First:
in your upload controller: make sure to set the correct allowed types

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Second:
update the array `$mimes` in your config/mimes.php:

```
'csv'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 
           'text/anytext', 
           'text/plain', 
           'text/x-comma-separated-values', 
           'text/comma-separated-values', 
           'application/octet-stream', 
           'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
           'application/x-csv', 
           'text/x-csv', 
           'text/csv', 
           'application/csv', 
           'application/excel', 
           'application/vnd.msexcel')
```

**UPDATE:**

you could use `print_r($_FILES)` in your upload controller to check for the mime-type missing. this would output something like:

```
[userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => teste1.csv
        [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
        [tmp_name] => C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\binaries\tmp\php8BFD.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 7880
    )
```

Comment: This worked for me, printing out $_FILES, thank you.  For those who are wondering .msg files needs the MIME type of: `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Hi, I was trying to upload xls file but able to do so, though I have updated the file type in config/mimes.php still can not figure out why the error is persistent "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Comment: @NazmulHasanSheum: this post is about csv mime type; for excel see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document. Btw. did you print_r($_FILES)?

Answer (score 1):

Add `‘text/plain’` to the CSV array in config/mimes.php to $mimes arrays, that is

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain'),
```

Comment: what is different in your 'csv' array ?